# Android Image Gallery in Grid Form

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am working on a project related to some image viewer. I get images from some server and display their thumbnail version on screen. I want to show the images in 3 x 2 matrix means 2 images per row and 3 rows. Images can be from 1 to 50. User may click on a particular image, its details are loaded and shown on screen. The problem I am facing is how to create a matrix view and when user click on a particular image, how to identify which image was clicked so that its details can be loaded and displayed...???

Comment: Take a look at GridView, it's surely what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridview is easy way.Besides with fixed matrix, you can use normal layout.GoodLuck